# Как парсить Яндекс.Маркет на python.Ошибка 403

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, http-status-code-403

Всем привет. Проблема с парсингом Яндекс.Маркет. Я хочу парсить телефоны. Когда я обращаюсь к Яндекс.Маркет, он мне возвращает 403 ответ, то есть отказ в доступе. Вместо html кода, который я хочу получить, чтобы потом его распарсить, я получаю html код, в котором мне говорит Яндекс, что мол мой ПК заражён (на самом деле с моим ПК всё норм). Ну и соответственно, сделать норм парсер не получаеться из-за 403 ошибки. С другими сайтами получается и всё норм, но с Яндекс какие-то проблемы у меня. Как обойти эту ошибку?

Ссылка на страницу для парсинга - https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/16814639/list?hid=91491&glfilter=16816262%3A16816264&onstock=1

```
import requests
import bs4


headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'})

url = "https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/16814639/list?hid=91491&glfilter=16816262%3A16816264&onstock=1"

r = requests.get(url,headers)
r.encoding="UTF8"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
sel = soup.select("div.d0N9PZYfeg a")
for i in sel:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Что Вы делаете, не ясно. Пришлите Ваш код или опишите детально, как Вы осуществляете парсинг

Comment: Извините,совсем забыл.

Comment: Не уверен, что без js-движка сможете работать с этим сайтом. Я бы попробовал selenium

Comment: @gil9red можно. Только нужно получать токены.

Comment: без js я не смогу парсить этот сайт?

Comment: Можете. Если браузере делает запрос и получает данные, то и Вы можете.

Comment: Магия. Очень странно. Но пока я не понимаю, в чём прикол, почему не работает curl со всеми хедерами.

Answer (score 3):

Убил какое-то катострофическое количество времени на вытаскивание данных. В чём причина была того, что у меня не работал скрипт, я так до конца и не разобрался. Скорее всего с сертификатами проблема была. Запустился из-под системного питона и всё заработало.

Укажите все заголовки, Которые  есть у меня

```
import requests

url = "https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/16814639/list?hid=91491&glfilter=16816262:16816264&onstock=1"

headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'market.yandex.ru',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Ваш код не рабочий. На выходе у него код 200, но эта страница запроса на ввод проверочного кода. Да, иногда Яндекс может и выдать правильную страницу, но это иногда, для парсинга такой подход не катит..
Похоже проще парсить интернет магазин, чем Яндекс.

Comment: @Александр Код рабочий. Вы описываете другую проблему. Да, для того, чтобы её решить, можно и нужно использовать сервисы анти-капчи. Например https://anti-captcha.com/ . Либо можно использовать кастомные сервисы. Ваше предложение выглядит как отказ от решения задачи.

Comment: У меня возвращается зашифрованный html код и в конце ошибка 403

Comment: Используете ли Вы anaconda или другой менеджер окружений (venv), например?

Comment: Нет не использую,это надо ?

Comment: @KRONYS есть подозрение, что у Вас проблема с сертификатами, такая же как была у меня. Только в вашем случае из-за засорённого системного питона, возникает проблема именно с системным питоном. Попробуйте воспользоваться каким-нибудь менеджером окружений или запустить скрипт на выделенном сервере. Таким образом, эксперимент будет точным и независимым

Comment: Хорошо попробую,напишу

Comment: Проверил на чистой linux ubuntu,результата тот-же. Зашифрованный html и ошибка 403

Comment: @KRONYS can we communicate in zoom?

Comment: yes, only I do not speak English well